# What is the best way to prevent duplicate values in databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

What is the best way to prevent duplicate values in databases ?

I have a table called names that has only one column called name that is unique (declared as unique attribute).

What is the best way to insert a new name (x) ?

Way1: Should I make a select query for the name x first to check if exist or not. Then make another query to insert the name iff it is not exists in the table.

Way2: Make only one query to insert the name and ignore the error if name already exists.

Comment: @wildplasser yes it has these constrains.

Comment: @wildplasser the OP already has that. The question is whether to check before insert or to handle the error on insert.

Comment: @Boris the Spider exactly

Comment: Oh, aha. I'm sorry. Well either avoid inserting them (this implies the framework *knowing* about the schema) or handling the error on the wrong inserts (this mostly assumes that the "user" can correct the violation manually) , then. A third way would be to `insert into ztable ... where not exists (...);` , but that would force you to retrieve the (new or existing) record in a second step.

Answer (score 3):

The second way is the better way.  Why run two queries when you can just run one?

When you declare the column as unique, you have told the database to do the extra work for ensure that this is true.  You don't need to do anything else -- other than check the errors on the return.

Comment: Agreed, as long as the code is specific about the error it catches.

Comment: Ok, What about if I want to insert multiple rows with one query.

    INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES ('x'), ('y'), ('z');

I tried it, if there is one of the names that is duplicated the whole query not executed. Is there a solution for this problem ?

Comment: @faressoft . . . In MySQL, you can use `insert . . . on duplicate key update`.

Answer (score 0):

- The first way works. After the action you can be sure that the record exists (unless some other error occured) You do need a second query (or some another mechanism) to retrieve the actual tuple, either the existing one or a fresly inserted one.
- The second way is terrible: the DBMS session is in error-state, {your current work has implicitely been rolled back, and your all cursors have been closed} So, you'll have to start your *work* allover again, hopefully without the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Database constraint will definitely take care about uniqueness, but if you have logic where you need to use last inserted ID to other child table, then only I think you will require to perform manual check before insert, else just ignore exception if raise due to duplication.

Answer (score 0):

The case you give is a simplified "upsert". Do a search for upsert and you will find answers to the more general question.  Some databases, like mysql provide for
insert ignore for this simple case.
Otherwise for the simple case you mention you can use the second approach.  For the more general upsert, it is surprisingly difficult to get it right. The issue is concurrent updates. In fact, I have not seen a satisfactory answer for general upserts. Some say to use "merge" but that is subject to concurrency issues.